# Removing rows and keeping consecutive rows pandas

Tags: pandas

I would like to omit the first row and keep x consecutive rows. 
in the example below i would like to keep 7. How do i achieve this?

```
df = pd.Series(range(1,101)).to_frame()
df.columns = ['numbers']
df['numbers'][1::7]

1       2
8       9
15     16
22     23
29     30
36     37
43     44
50     51
57     58
64     65
71     72
78     79
85     86
92     93
99    100
```

I would like to keep the values below but continue to the next row sequence. 
so remove 1 then keep 2 to 7. then remove 8 and keep 9 to 14

```
df = pd.Series(range(1,101)).to_frame()
df.columns = ['numbers']
df['numbers'][1:7]
1    2 
2    3 
3    4 
4    5 
5    6 
6    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `drop`

```
df.drop(df.index[::7])

    numbers
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         5
5         6
6         7
8         9
9        10
10       11
11       12
12       13
13       14
15       16
16       17
17       18
18       19
..      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Or `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.index % 7 != 0]
```

giving

```
    numbers
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         5
5         6
6         7
8         9
9        10
10       11
11       12
12       13
13       14
15       16
16       17
...      ...
```

Comment: For golfing purposes this can be reduced to `df[df.index % 7 != 0]`.  Pandas `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__` will interpret a boolean series/array as something to be aligned along the index axis.  Nice answer